# App saves 2 video files after recording via Android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, video

I wrote code to capture a video via Android intent and to save the video to a specific directory with a specific file name.

Now, the video does in fact get saved to that directory, with that specific file name. However, I noticed in my phone's gallery, the same video is stored there with default file name (ie. 2016_2_24.mp4)

I don't want this extra video file in my gallery. Here's the code I have so far:

```
videoPath = "/X1," + num1 +
             ",Y1," + num2 +
             ",X2," + num3 +
             ",Y2," + num4 +
             ",A," + num5 +
             ",G," + num6 +
             ",la," + num7 +
             ",lo," + num8+ ".mp4";

path = new File(mFile, videoPath);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(path));
startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_INTENT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are delegating video recording to a third-party app. The third-party app can do whatever it wants. It can:

- Record the video to the location provided in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`
- Record the video elsewhere and make a copy in the location provided in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`
- Ignore `EXTRA_OUTPUT` entirely (which arguably is a bug, but there are plenty of buggy camera apps)

There are thousands of Android device models and thousands of camera apps, both pre-installed apps and apps installed by users. The behavior of these apps vary and can encompass any of the scenarios that I outlined above.

Only use `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` (or `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`) if video recording is not essential and that you don't mind these sorts of problems.

In this case, if you are getting a video in the location provided in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, count your blessings, and don't worry about the second copy, as you can't prevent it or really do much about it.

Comment: is there another way to record/save videos with out a copy?

Comment: @EbadSaghar: You can build your own video recording solution using the camera APIs and `MediaRecorder`. This is not easy. However, there is no `EXTRA_PLEASE_DO_NOT_MAKE_A_COPY` or anything for you to somehow tell a third-party app to not make a copy. Ideally, it wouldn't be doing that anyway. Ideally, I'd have hair.

Comment: Yea, I can make my own recording solution using the camera APIs. But that's a lot of work. Although being young, handsome and with a full set of beautiful hair, I could be all that AND become the next Mark Zuckerberg, but that's a lot of work to become.